# Hissing sound in headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

Today I tried Ubuntu on my laptop Asus n550jx 64 bit version. Everything works fine except there is constant static/ hissing in headphones (in laptop speaker too, but its too silent to be heard). It uses intel 4th generation sound drivers or something liek that, on windows realtek hd drivers. Also hissing is constant - it doesn't stop if there is no music playing or something like, pop only happens when Ubuntu boots. Hissing doesn't become louder if there max volume, it happens even if there is speaker on mute( sound of hissing changes thought).

What have tried:

- Mute built in microphone- no effect
- Check playback settings with alsamixer. There was something loopback which turned off made hissing quieter, but its still annoying
- Checked sound card power saving which was turned off

So its something like that...

Oh and there is no hissing on windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

The following solved it for my `ux501VW` laptop

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
sudo hdajackretask
```

1. Select both **Show unconnected pins** and **Advanced override** in the Options
2. Override Pin ID **0x16** Changing Device to: **headphones**
3. Click the **Install boot override** button
4. Reboot

Comment: This worked for me on Dell XPS 13 9350.  I had to change pin 0x12 (internal mic) to disabled. Finally I have peace.

Comment: This works, but I seem to have to click on the down-arrow for sound/lights/wifi/etc. options for it to take effect.

Comment: worked in Linux Mint Desktop

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late to the party but I solved this on Ubuntu 17.04 by doing the following:

Open terminal and type the following:

```
alsamixer
```

and then press F6 and select your sound card. Use your arrow keys to decrease the volume where the hissing sound disappears (I solved it by decreasing it to green area only. [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC2bl.png)). After that, adjust volume using standard volume control on Ubuntu (from Unity menu). You may have to do this every time you plug/unplug sound card but it has given me peace of mind really.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: After all these time I have spent looking for a solution this was the fix for me!

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Was thinking of downgrading back to Ubuntu 16 because of this :D

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers in this thread that worked for many other users, worked for me. I thought the problem was in my audio card driver so I did a little research and found this magic line.

```
sudo setfacl -m u:username:rw /dev/snd/*
```

It solved the problem for me with no more hissing in my headphones. You can find the original answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249071/1364590).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how it works, but the hissing sound goes away when i enabled auto-mute mode in alsamixer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1267057)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/#background_noise .
I could not make it run on boot, but its something.