# Internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, upgrade, sound, pulseaudio, 20.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 lts from 18.04 lts. After reboot audio is not working. I tried to reinstall `pulseaudio` and `alsa` but still not working.
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio`
`sudo alsa force-reload`
still not working.

output

```
 └─▶ inxi -SMA
System:    Host: Wizard Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Portable System: Dell product: Vostro 2520 v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0V1NDP v: A11 serial: <superuser/root required> BIOS: Dell v: A11 date: 02/24/2014 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-26-generic
```

output

```
└─▶ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: Hi there i think we have the same problem...see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230383/soundcard-not-detected-by-pulseaudio-but-by-alsa

Comment: Try this patch, was having the same issue and it fixed it.


https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/690180

Comment: Headphones not working out of the box with Ubuntu's new version? Need to install package from untrusted source to fix?
It must be a joke ...

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1249071/1071912 Try this solution. @framontb

Comment: @InjamulMohammadMollah
Doesn't work for me (Ubuntu Focal Fossa)

Comment: This is silly but After days of searching, upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 then installing fresh 20.04 i was not able to solve the problem, which finally got solved by just 
going into BIOS -> disable Internal Speakers -> apply changes -> Enable again -> Apply changes -> Exit. 

Voila Problem is solved :) :) (Dell Latitude 3510)

Comment: Related:: [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just in case somebody reached this question looking for a solution. The only native solution (no need to do something external) is provided by @Nate on this link https://askubuntu.com/a/37609/9598 which I reproduce partially here to give you a clue on how to fix this problem.

> I [...] noticed that the ACLs weren't set in `/dev/snd`

```
sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/*
```

and then do a reboot of your computer.

Running this command in a terminal will fix the issue.

Thank you very much [Michael Butler](https://askubuntu.com/users/9268/michael-butler)

Comment: it worked to me, after a reboot.

Comment: This worked for me too

Comment: How to make it permanent? When I reboot this fix is gone.

Comment: I don't know under which circumstances it is removed on reboot, but you can add this command to your crontab using `sudo crontab -e` then add `@reboot setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/*`. Maybe you are using a removable sound card? If so, just make sure your sound device is ready on start. Otherwise you may need to wait for a while `sleep 60` (for 60 seconds delay), before the command runs.

Answer (score 19):

Your speakers may be detected as unplugged which causes them to be ignored.

**Temporary fix:**

1. `sudo apt install pavucontrol`
2. Run `pavucontrol`
3. Configuration tab > Profile > Analogue Stereo Output (unplugged) (unavailable)

Speakers should work but it will reset when headphones are unplugged or system rebooted.

**Permanent fix:**

1. `sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui`
2. Run `hdajackretask`
3. Parser hints > jack_detect = no
4. Apply now
5. Install boot override

Comment: The second one worked for me, even if there were error messages when I applied it.

Comment: Tried everything for asus zenbook pro ux434f but didnt work. Finally permanent fix worked for me after a restart (didn't installed boot override though).

I will read the documentation and would then install boot override.

Comment: Haven't tried the first solution, but the second one worked for Realtek ALC897 (ASUS PRIME H570-PLUS motherboard) and Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Great  fixed my problem with hp probook 450 g4

Answer (score 12):

I think i have a workaround for your problem:
Try

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

This brought my soundcard back to life. But it doesn't survive a reboot, so I am working on making the change persistent...
See:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/

Comment: I already tried this.. see at question

Comment: this works for me on Dell XPS L502X, and keeps working after sleep.

Comment: @geoffrey, why shouldn't it be working after sleep?

Comment: Well because it's said that it doesn't persist after reboot. I don't know the internal working. I just wanted to add the info, maybe it could help someone diagnosing the problem better.

Comment: @geoffrey, reboot has nothing to do with sleep. Sleep changes nothing, your comment almost certainly will not help.

Answer (score 10):

What fixed it for me after an upgrade to 20.04 was:

```
sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

Then reboot.
Quick and easy so worth trying!

Comment: this worked for me. None of the other things did.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I don't have timidity-daemon installed

Comment: This worked for me as well!

Comment: I don't have timidity-daemon installed too

Comment: That helped. Dell XPS here. Can you explain why?

Comment: Wow !!! Thanks for the trick !!!

Comment: Ha, this was exactly my case. I installed timidity yesterday, and today sound disappeared (failed to switch back). Removing timidity fixed it...

Comment: Kernel:5.4.0-90-generic. After that I added `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` and reboot, nothing.  After that I changed in `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`  and added `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` (in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`), and blacklisted `blacklist snd_soc_skl` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and a reboot... nothing again. Then after `sudo apt purge timidity-daemon` and `sudo alsa force-reload` did it without rebooting again.

Comment: I made `apt purge pipewire`. `inxi -SMA` then reports `PulseAudio` server instead of `PipeWire` and the sound works in my case.

Answer (score 5):

Mine is a Dell Inspiron 1525. I tried all the solutions listed here on askubuntu.com and all over the web but of no use and finally to find that it is a bug in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS/kernel-5.4 (Focal kernel) where the internal sound card is not detected. The driver soc-skl is disabled by
default from kernel-5.4. Kernels 5.5, 5.6 all disabled this driver. Read the bug reports [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1869799) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1864061).

It affects many users. There is nothing much we can do until the kernels are fixed.

For me, the headphones and mic are working. For the time being, connecting the headphone jacks to external speakers solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the solutions listed here on askubuntu.com and all over the web but of no use and finally to find that it is a bug in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS/kernel-5.4 (Focal kernel) where the internal sound card is not detected.

@Greg gave me The patch which is working for me

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kaihengfeng/fix-lp1869819
sudo apt-get upgrade`

Now Sound is working fine.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/690180

https://launchpad.net/~kaihengfeng/+archive/ubuntu/fix-lp1869819

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and tried everything else. For me the problem was built-in front audio in a desktop: it stopped working after a reboot. Running `aplay -l` said it saw no cards, but `lspci -v` reported an `Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller`. Its output didn't include any lines for `Kernel modules`. Googling told me that other people were using `snd_hda_intel` as the driver, but `lsmod | grep snd` gave no results. I didn't even have a `/proc/asound` directory; it was just missing.

It turns out I needed to run this to install the missing driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

I actually did have the drivers installed for a previous kernel (visible if I said `find /lib/modules -name 'snd-hda*'`), but for some reason I didn't have the `-extra` package installed for my current kernel.

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: This fixed on my dell laptop the problem with sound, wifi network and hdmi output not working problem after upgrading from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.3. For some reason, during upgrade, the `-extra` package didn't got installed