# Dummy output after standby since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have a problem similar to the one described here: [20.04: internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/20-04-internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgradi)

None of the solutions posted there worked for me, also **the problem is a bit different in my case**.

In a summary: since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, the audio normally works for me. However, sometimes after I put my system in standby and then resume it, my audio no longer works and I see only "Dummy output" in the list of audio output devices.

Restarting the computer solves the issue for me. However, it's quite annoying that I have to restart it every time.

```
sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
  *-usb:0
       description: Video
       product: USB 2.0 Camera
       vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:3.1
       version: 0.00
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7330000-f7333fff
```

Comment: What does `sudo lshw -C multimedia` tell you?

Comment: Does `pulseaudio -k` fix it temporarily?

Comment: @starkus I'vem updated my question with that detail. I will try `pulseaudio -k` next time I'll have the same issue (as it occurs randomly)

Comment: You could `echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` give a try. Further reading --> https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

Comment: You can see this answer if you want to, https://askubuntu.com/a/1244118/1071912