# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio, 20.04, audio-player, fujitsu-siemens, audio-sync

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. After reboot audio is not working. I tried to reinstall pulseaudio and alsa but still not working:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio 
sudo alsa force-reload
```

[image: Screenshot showing AlsaMixer]

Still not working.

Comment: Before reinstalling pulseaudio, you have checked all relevent settings there, right?

Comment: can you see what type of audio out you can find in settings?,line out or simmilar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [20.04: internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/20-04-internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgradi)

Answer (score 1):

In alsamixer, disable "loopback".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.It helps to have something playing in the background while performing these steps. What worked was:

1. Opening a terminal and logging in as root

   ```bsh
   sudo su
   ```

   (Or however you like to log into root.)
2. Edit the file found at `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf` and change any instances of `Element` (such as `[Element Desktop Speaker]`) from `switch = off` to `switch = on`.

   ```bsh
   gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf
   ```
3. Reboot.