# No sound in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, usb-creator

I upgraded ubuntu 19.10 to ubuntu along side windows 10, my processor is AMD(R) Sempron(tm),2650 apuwith redon(tm)r 3x2,R3,1.45, I faced sound problem, When I used ubuntu 19.10 along side windows 10 the sound system of both is ok, but when I install ubuntu 20.04 the sound is gone for ubuntu but in windows 10 it is ok, what should I do?

Comment: Your question lacks minimal details. Please elaborate by running some commands and posting outputs which appears to be fishy.Try troubleshooting. If not, do it now. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: This may help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/20-04-internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgradi

Answer (score 0):

I recently was able to get around the no sound Issue with only the Dummy Output selection for the sound card by pasting the following command into terminal. I found this solution here. 
help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`