# Problem with audio with kubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04

so my university requested me to install kubuntu. I've always had problems with the micro but audio was working well. After rebooting my laptop, it does not emit any  sounds at all and the audio control has dissapeared and I can't mamage to acces it.

Please, I need some help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgrading-from