# Ubuntu, sound disappeared

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

- Ubuntu 21.04, 64 bit.
- Just updated to kernel `5.11.0-25-generic` and sound disappeared.

```
modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

Displays absolutely nothing. No error message, no missing. Nothing. Is that expected?

```
System:
  Host: rabbit Kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: GNOME 3.38.4 Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20QVCTO1WW v: ThinkPad X1 Extreme 2nd 
  serial: <superuser required> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20QVCTO1WW v: SDK0R32862 WIN 
  serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: N2OET52W (1.39 ) 
  date: 04/28/2021 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-25-generic
```

```
aplay -l
aplay: device_list:276: no soundcards found...
```

```
sudo lshw -C sound

  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:159 memory:4000108000-400010bfff memory:4000000000-40000fffff
```

Any ideas?

- I tried to add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `alsa-base.conf`. Still no luck. Purged and reinstalled pulsaudio packages, alsa packages. Still no sound.
- Also tried instead to add `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` still no sound.
- Tried to use previous kernel, still no sound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgrading-from)

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed with this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1249071/877575

Wondering why reinstalling all packages did not fix this.